# Eclipse plugins installation with multiple features

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing a series of plugins grouped under a feature "A".
Now I need a new plugin with different functionality which should be under a different feature "B".

I want that feature A includes feature B, so that gets installed together. So far so good.
I put both feature in the same update site.

Installation is working, but I need to update feature B with a different "lifecycle" than feature A
(more frequently).
The update is not working since **feature A requires feature B at some precise version**, but I have built a new version of feature B for the purpose of the update.

How to manage or solve this situation without a product file?

Thank you!

Comment: If you add feature B in feature A as a Dependency rather than as an Included Feature you can specify a match rule for the version (Version Greater or Equal for example). Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes something like that. But in my case, users have feature A already installed. I would like feature B to be installed automatically, as an included feature. Using a dependency each user has to install the feature as a brand new.. I believe...